PLS Regression on data with high number of zeros in dependent variable
I want to perform a PLS regression on a data set coming from spectral images (NIRS). My goal is to relate the different spectra to the total amount of a compound. To do this, I have a dataset consisting of thousands of samples where the amount of this compound varies from 0 to around 25.
However, as can be seen in the attached figure, there are a large number of samples that do not have a detectable amount of that compound or simply do not produce it. In the case of classification problems, this could introduce problems due to unbalance between classes, however, I do not know if in regression this could be the case. I have been reading about Hurdle models for data inflated with 0, however, I am not sure how to proceed since the ultimate goal is to select the bands of the spectrum most related to the total amount of the compound. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I thought of PLS regression because it is a common technique to determine the concentration of a compound through spectra obtained by NIRS. Because the number of independent variables (spectra) is about 4200, and looking for information on handling this type of data, I found a reference on the web. The author selected the bands of the spectrum most related to the amount of compound through a double loop in which he first optimized the number of components to transform the data and then selected the appropriate number of spectral bands to choose, through the fitting of several models, the one with the lowest MSE. Initially, this method seemed appropriate to me although I am not sure how to proceed due to the high distribution of zeros in the data.

Hi, just to be sure, your predictor matrix is mutidimensional while your variable of interest is uni- or multi- variate ? If your compound is univariate I am not totally convinced that PLS is the right model here, specifically for feature selection. Alternatives, such as elastic-net or even sPLS for multivariate outcome could perform better in this case.

Why do you want to use partial least squares regression?  Your reason may influence the answers.

Hello. My variable of interest is the quantity/percentage of the compound, a univariate variable. I have edited the original post to add more information

I will try a general response using two approaches for your specific problem.
